# When trying to connect to a pool it says ethminer.exe is written wrong or wasn't found

Tags: mining-pools, windows

So I started 2 days ago with farming eth and I wanted to join a pool. So I searched up a good pool, for me I chose Nanopool and looked at the tutorials on how to connect. 
They say type this into your command console (windows 10 user):

> ethminer.exe -G -F http://eth1.nanopool.org:8888/(your adress)
>   So I put my adress in:
>   ethminer.exe -G -F http://eth1.nanopool.org:8888/0x664c9F5Ef393a53FcB58F7B26E6CcF1b272D3fD1
>   But afterwards my cmd line says:

The command "ethminer.exe" is either misspelled or
could not be found.
But ethminer is running at the same time and geth is updating the chain constantly I don't know why this happened. Thanks for the help.
Andy

Answer (score 0):

Ethminer.exe is put into the /bin folder of wherever you installed it.  Best to just click the search bar, type cmd, hit enter.  Then go to the folder with ethminer.exe and paste your command there.

If you're using nanopool, there is no reason to have geth running.  That's only if you're going to be solo mining.

Comment: So I should just type the same command into a new cmd window.

Comment: But when I do that and ethminer is running in the backround it still says the same thing.

Comment: know it says that the system cant find the path. What?

Answer (score 0):

If you’ve already been using `ethminer`, Windows Defender probably deleted your `ethminer` because it thinks it is malware. You will need to periodically reinstall it (since Defender turns itself on every once in a while, even if you disable it). You can also add your `ethminer` to the Windows Defender exclusions list.

If you haven’t used `ethminer`, then it’s probably a path issue if you’ve already downloaded it.